# GIT Can't push after pull other branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was working on `admin` branch, but I needed some things done in `develop` branch, so `git pull origin develop` was my choice.

After some days working (still on `admin` but with thoose `develop` things) I want to push to `admin` so everything gets OK.

I get this error

 `! [rejected]        admin -> admin (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.mygit.com:mygit/mygit.git'
consejo: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
consejo: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
consejo: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
consejo: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

If I try to do a `git pull` I am getting things from `develop` again and breaks everything I've made (I'm doing with `rebase`) even if I do `git pull origin admin`.

I was the only one working on `admin` branch, and `develop` one person too without touching  `admin`

`git branch -vv`

```
* admin   238eab7 [origin/admin: ahead 37, behind 9] Entidades remodeladas. Mapeo de entidades separadas a YAML para mejor organización Limpieza de varias cosas que sobraban (bundles y demás) Separadas las configuraciones por tipo. Separados los servicios por bundle y tipo siguiendo las recomendaciones de Symfony2
  develop 7cc5c84 [origin/develop: behind 22] Eurotax funcinoando. Quitado Memcached en el entorno de DEV para DQL y metido en PROD
```

Comment: Is your `develop` branch tracking set up as tracking branch for `origin/develop`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean neither how to look for it... I'm pretty sloth on github and I've beein always doin push/pull with rebase only... :(

Comment: Ok please add the output of the command `git branch -vv` to your question.

Comment: Done. The first line is my last commit, which I want to push to admin. The second line seems to be a commit I did few weeks ago on develop branch (when I was using it before moving to admin in order to work on that branch)

Comment: Ok so please go to your admin branch and pull all new stuff from remote that have changed maybe.

Comment: I am at admin branch. It says so when I do `git branch`. If I do `git pull` I'm getting things from `develop`, that is the problem... `admin` branch hasn't changes, the last change was from me about 5 days ago, before I did `git pull origin develop` to get things from that branch, but I was on `admin` branch already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83973/discussion-between-ckruczek-and-robert-w-hunter).

Answer (score 0):

If you did the pull with rebase option, you take the admin changes and put on top of develop changes(with new commits). so the commits on the admin branch do not exist on your local branch anymore, it got replace by new ones. if you are shure that your changes are correct you have to push with --force option. like:

git push --force origin admin

When you do a pull with --rebase option, you have to use --force to replace the contents on remote repository.